# Nuvoton M031 SysTick

Tags: microcontroller, timer

I am trying to learn Nuvoton microcontrollers. I have NuMaker-M031SD. I am trying to blink a led with a button. I wanted to use a simple state machine to blink led.

I used to work on STM32, so I know there is a function called HAL_GetTick() to get millisecond to do real time job. I searched in CMSIS and driver libraries to find that function but I couldn't find it.

Here is my code:

```
#include "M031Series.h"

#define TIME (200)

void SYS_Init(void);
void SysTick_Handler(void);
void Inc_Tick(void);
uint32_t Get_Tick(void);

void SYS_Init()
{
    /* Unlock protected registers */
    SYS_UnlockReg();

    /* Enable clock source */
    CLK_EnableXtalRC(CLK_PWRCTL_HIRCEN_Msk);

    /* Waiting for clock source ready */
    CLK_WaitClockReady(CLK_STATUS_HIRCSTB_Msk);

    /* Disable PLL first to avoid unstable when setting PLL */
    CLK_DisablePLL();

    /* Set PLL frequency */
    CLK->PLLCTL = (CLK->PLLCTL & ~(0x000FFFFFul)) | 0x0008C03Eul;

    /* Waiting for PLL ready */
    CLK_WaitClockReady(CLK_STATUS_PLLSTB_Msk);

    /* If the defines do not exist in your project, please refer to the related clk.h in the Header folder appended to the tool package. */
    /* Set HCLK clock */
    CLK_SetHCLK(CLK_CLKSEL0_HCLKSEL_HIRC, CLK_CLKDIV0_HCLK(1));

    /* Set PCLK-related clock */
    CLK->PCLKDIV = (CLK_PCLKDIV_APB0DIV_DIV1 | CLK_PCLKDIV_APB1DIV_DIV1);

    /* Enable IP clock */
    CLK_EnableModuleClock(ISP_MODULE);
    CLK_EnableSysTick(CLK_CLKSEL0_STCLKSEL_HCLK, 0);

    /* Update System Core Clock */
    /* User can use SystemCoreClockUpdate() to calculate SystemCoreClock. */
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

    /* Lock protected registers */
    SYS_LockReg();
}

volatile uint32_t u32_Tick;

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    Inc_Tick();
}

void Inc_Tick()
{
    u32_Tick++;
}

uint32_t Get_Tick()
{
    return u32_Tick;
}



uint8_t buttonFT=0,ledState;
uint32_t firstLedTime,secondLedTime;

int main(void)
{   
    SYS_Init();
    SysTick_Config(1000);
    
    GPIO_SetMode(PB,BIT14,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    GPIO_SetMode(PC,BIT1,GPIO_MODE_INPUT);

    
    while(1)
    {
            if(PC1 == 0)
            {
                if(buttonFT==0)
                {
                    buttonFT = 1;
                    ledState = 1;
                }   
            }
    
        switch(ledState)
        {
            case 0:{ledState=0;} break;
            case 1:{firstLedTime = Get_Tick(); ledState = 2;} break;
            case 2:
            {
                secondLedTime = Get_Tick();
                if(secondLedTime - firstLedTime > TIME)
                {
                    PB14 = 1;
                    ledState =0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        
    }

}
```

So I created my own Get_Tick() function to do that job. But when I read the techincal reference manual of Nuvoton about SysTick. It says "***When system timer is enabled, it will count down from the value in the SysTick Current Value Register (SYST_VAL) to zero***".

It obviously does not doing what I thought it would do. It counts from SYST_VAL to zero but I want it to count like millis() function. I couldn't find the function to get millisecond.

What is the equilavent function of HAL_GetTick() or millis() in Nuvoton M031?

**I edited my code after first comment but I couldn't make it to blink the led.**

Comment: That's not how it works on STM32 either. In STM32 you don't read the timer count register. The timer counts ticks one way or another and generates systick interrupts every millisecond (or some other timebase). The interrupt function then just increases a variable and the value of that variable can be read with a HAL_getticks function.

Comment: So should I call IncTick function in SysTick_Handler() and increase tick ? Also create another Get_Tick functions which returns tick value ?